# How to support Є in a LaTeX document

Tags: font-encodings

I am writing an article introducing TeX. The sentence may look like:

> … the name of the system named TeX, which is original from Greece words ΤЄΧ.

When I am using this symbol in my LaTeX document:

> ```
> ΤЄΧ
> ```

I found the symbol `Є` could not be rendered in the document. How to make LaTeX support this symbol?

This is the demo:

```
\documentclass{dolphinbook}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage[bookmarksopen,bookmarksdepth=4]{hyperref}
    
\begin{document}

ΤЄΧ

\end{document}
```

this is my custom class file:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{dolphinbook}
\LoadClass[8pt]{book}

\RequirePackage{listings}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}

\lstset{      
    alsolanguage= XML,  
    tabsize=4, 
    frame=shadowbox, 
    commentstyle=\color{red!50!green!50!blue!50},
    frameround=tttt,  
    rulesepcolor=\color{red!20!green!20!blue!20}, 
    keywordstyle=\color{blue!90}\bfseries, 
    showstringspaces=false,
    stringstyle=\ttfamily,  
    keepspaces=true,  
    breakindent=22pt, 
    breaklines=true,
    numbers=left,  
    stepnumber=1,   
    numberstyle={\color[RGB]{0,192,192}\tiny},  
    numbersep=8pt,  
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    showspaces=false, 
    escapechar=`,
    flexiblecolumns=true,  
    breaklines=true,   
    breakautoindent=true,
    breakindent=4em,       
    aboveskip=1em, 
    tabsize=4,  
    showstringspaces=false,  
    backgroundcolor=\color[RGB]{245,245,244}, 
    escapeinside={``}{\_},   
    fontadjust,  
    captionpos=t,  
    framextopmargin=2pt,
    framexbottommargin=2pt,
    abovecaptionskip=-3pt,
    belowcaptionskip=3pt,  
    xleftmargin=1em,
    xrightmargin=1em,  
    texcl=true
}
```

Comment: you need a font that supports cyrillic. But why on earth do you want to typeset TeX like this??

Comment: Have you tried the standard macro, *viz.*, `\TeX`?

Comment: I have edit my question that shows why need to input the Greece words ` ΤЄΧ`.

Comment: By the by, `8pt` is not an option `book` recognises.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorry, but this is a *non sequitur*.

The letter you'd like to use is Є U+0404 CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER UKRAINIAN IE, which doesn't look like Greek.

The story of this letter is long. Of course it derives from the (uppercase) letter “epsilon” of Greek, like most of the Cyrillic letterforms. In the uncial script the epsilon was written in a more roundish fashion than in the ancient capital script, where there always was a straight vertical bar (the horizontal ones were usually slanted, though, like in the Phoenician script). Ukrainian uses it as a distinct letter from Е (U+0415 CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER IE) that in Russian is pronounced the same as Ukrainian Є (iotated e), whereas in the latter language the Е is pronounced “e”.

Using U+0404 is definitely not a choice for describing the origin of the TeX logo. You may instead use lowercase Greek, which would be much sounder.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}

\newfontfamily{\greekalph}{Libertinus Serif}[Scale=MatchUppercase]

\begin{document}

The name of the program is \TeX, which Knuth derived from the
first three letters of the Greek word {\greekalph τέχνη},
meaning ``craft, skill, art''.

\end{document}
```

[image]